# て form can be used to indicate the past?

Tags: grammar

i've seen a few sentences like this one:新しいコロナウイルスが広がって,which instead of た , て was used, is it an even more  casual way to make the past tense?

Comment: 広がって is just a te-form, which can not show any tense by itself. This sentence can be about something in the future depending on the context.